# How to select each next() element of the list and unselect prev()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I've been stuck with this one for quite awhile. Any help would be highly appreciated.

What I need is, once a client hits > arrow the current li element will be inactive, and next li element will be active. And the process will continue until the last li of the list will be the only active one.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 39){    
    $('#nav li .active').next().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

I am open to any suggestions and modifications of the code :)

Comment: Can you post your HTML? If the `li` is what has `.active`, then your selector needs to be `$('#nav li.active')`

Comment: @MichaelCoker you are so right! i just erased that extra space, and everything worked the way i wanted it to! thank you!

Comment: awesome no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` (JQuery). syntax can be like this `$('#nav li .active').each(function(index){Yourcodehere})`
Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 39){
      // Capture active li element
      $active_li = $('#nav li.active');
      // Clear active from all li elements
      $('#nav li').each(function () {
         this.removeClass('active');
      });
      // Set active for next li element
      $active_li.next().addClass('active');
      }
  });
```

Or even maybe:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 39){
      $('#nav li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a way to accomplish this. The markup will obviously be different. (JSFiddle below - be sure to click in the HTML frame before pressing the right arrow button):

https://jsfiddle.net/d13kwz1p/

Example HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="active">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Example JS

```
var menu = $('#menu');
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        var current = menu.find('.active');
    var next = current.next();
    current.removeClass('active');
    if (current.is(':last-child')) {
        menu.find(':first-child').addClass('active');
    } else {
        next.addClass('active');
    }
  }
});
```

Example CSS:

```
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#menu li.active {
  background: #ccc;
}
```